# Alternativa a genymotion en mxlinux21/debian11

Tags: android, android-studio, linux, debian, genymotion

Para que funcione genymotion en linux, necesita del driver privativo si tienes una tarjeta nvidia. En mi caso el controlador que necesito es el nvidia-340 pero debian a decidido desde su version debian11 quitar el soporte al driver nvidi-340 por fallas en la seguridad.

¿Como reemplazo genymotion en mxlinux21/debian11, hay alguna alternativa?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

La mejor alternativa y mas rapida hay que decirlo es androvm:

Una maquina virtual que se ejecuta en virtualbox con android 4.1.1 con arquitectura de hadware x86. bastante ligera, mas que genymotion(aunque son ellos los que estan detras de este proyecto) y muchisimo mas que la tortuga androidx86.

Para desplazarte por el sistema puedes instalar:Simple Control para Android. Muestras los botones en la pantalla.

para instalar alguna apk que no aparezca en play store la buscas de la siquiente manera en google ejemplo:

```
play store 86 android 4.1.1
```

y descargas el apk y lo instalar, tambien de la misma manera puedes instalar:

```
nova launcher 86 android 4.1.1
```

Para actualizar el lanzador de aplicaciones y demas.

Puedes decargar androvm desde: http://minhluan.net/en/blog/androvm-install-android-on-windows-ubuntu-macos-with-virtualbox/

Puedes elegir la opcion: AndroVM for tablet with gapp. Trae la play store instalada aunque en mi caso tuve que reinstalar playstore.

Pues eso es todo amigos disfruten su nuevo android en linux.